# Mac losing connection every 10 minutes. Have to turn wifi off/on every time

Tags: network, wifi

I'm having a problem with my Mac Air with OSX X Yosemite.

It loses the wifi connection every about 10 minutes. 
Interestingly, connection summary shows Internet as recheable:

[image]

To solve it, I have to turn off/on my wifi every time.

I had tried [this solution](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/25/fix-wi-fi-problems-os-x-yosemite/), which seems to work for a while, 
but does not solve definitely.

**This problem doesn't occurs in others devices using the same Wifi**

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to El Capitan (10.11)?

Comment: Not yet.. Without time right now. Upgrade would solve this issue?

Comment: I can't promise it would, but I believe many people have found that applying OS X updates fixed the widespread WiFi connection problems that people were seeing a couple of years ago.

Comment: I've experienced the same problem on El Capitan, so upgrading might not solve this issue. Followed a guide myself and it seems to work.

Comment: @Hoshts which guide?

Comment: @nekomatic I updated the to El Capitan and solved this problem for some days. Now, its back again..

Comment: @Rodrigo it's the same guide as you mentioned.